# Under what circumstance does CALL return nonzero?

Tags: evm, assembly

Reading the yellow paper http://yellowpaper.io/ documentation for `CALL`.

> µ'_s[0] ≡ x
>   where x = 0 if the code execution for this operation failed due to an exceptional halting, Z(σ, µ, I) = > or if µs[2] > σ[Ia]b (not enough funds) or Ie = 1024 (call depth limit reached); x = 1 otherwise.

Would all of these cases cause an exception and halt execution, therefore preventing `CALL` from returning?

It's like dropping a nuclear bomb with a greeting card attached... useless because the greeting card is gone on impact.

Answer (score 2):

> Would all of these cases cause an exception and halt execution, therefore preventing CALL from returning?

It stops the code being `CALL`ed from continuing, but it returns control to the caller with a zero return value (indicating failure).

You can try it out in Remix:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;

contract Fail {
    function fail() public {
        revert();
    }
}

contract TestCall {
    Fail f = new Fail();

    // This will revert.
    function test1() public {
        f.fail();
    }

    // This transaction will succed, but the CALL returns 0.
    function test2() public {
        f.call(bytes4(keccak256("fail()")));
    }
}
```

Oh, and I think you phrased your question backwards, but the answer to "Under what circumstance does CALL return nonzero?" is "When the CALL succeeds."